# append output of rm -rf to a file

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to append the filename deleted from `rm -rf *.log` to another file, say `xyz.abc`. Is there a way to do that?

It should append all the `.log` files to `xyz.abc`. Tried but failed, so asking here.

Comment: If `rm -rf` doesn't emit that list of files as output, then you're asking for something different than "appending output of rm -rf". Could you be clear about what the results should look like? Is the intent something human-readable? Unambiguously machine-parseable (in which case a list of filenames needs to be NUL-delimited or shell-escaped)? Something else?

Comment: Here's how my output should look like.
I have 3 log files, 1.log 2.log 3.log
I am applying rm -rf *.log
And I want a file namd xyz.abc to be created that stores 
1.log
2.log

Comment: Whenever files are deleted with `rm` from this one console instance / script? Whenever files are deleted with any method by any process on the system? Do you want an `xyz.abc` per directory (since you show filenames with no directory names in your example)? One globally with full paths?

Comment: And how should a filename that includes a literal newline inside its name be displayed? Should it be shell-escaped? NUL-delimited?

Comment: (In your example given in the comment, you aren't specifying delimiters -- whitespace vs newlines etc; if you mean just simple whitespace, then there's a question about how filenames with spaces should be stored).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are complicating what I asked for. I just have a single query. I want 3 .log files to be removed and store the name of the logs files in another file say abc.xyz. You can give me one-line command or a scripts. Anything would do.

I have been trying to delete log files that are been generated automatically each time we follow the build+install on various environments and these logs are not at all needed after say a week. So, if you could help.

Comment: The point is that you didn't ask clearly enough that I don't know how much complication is required for an answer to meet your needs (since those needs were, prior to the comment above, undescribed). Your comment, for instance, sounds like you don't need to override `rm` at all in the general case, but are just logging files deleted by a single, specific instance of `rm`. That's *not at all* how I understood your original question before that clarification.

Comment: The other reason I asked those questions is to make you aware of potential requirements you might not have been previously aware of. If it was important for the list of names to be correctly machine-readable across the entire domain space, and you didn't _know_ that legit filenames could contain newlines, you might wrongly think that you could use literal, unescaped names with newlines separating them as a format for the file. You didn't tell us whether correct machine readability was a requirement, so why should we assume it isn't?

Comment: okay, I'm sorry if I'm unable to express my question in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `rm -rf *.log` doesn't print any output; it silently deletes the specified files.

The `-r` option *probably* doesn't make much sense in this case, and could potentially be dangerous. If you're trying to remove all `*.log` files in the current directory, all you need is

```
rm -f *.log
```

The `-r` matters only if you have one or more *directories* whose names end in `.log`; it will then recursively remove those directories and all their contents.

Assuming you just want to delete all `*.log` files in the current directory and append their names to `xyz.abc`, here's how I'd do it:

```
for file in *.log ; do
    echo "$file" >> xyz.abc
    rm -f "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to write a little script that does it for you, and use that instead of the system's real `rm` program. So you could write something like this and save it as, say,  `$HOME/RemoveLogs`

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.log -print -exec rm {} +; >> xyz.abc
```

Then, in the Terminal, type the following just once to make the script executable

```
chmod +x $HOME/RemoveLogs
```

and then, whenever you want to remove the logs, just run

```
$HOME/RemoveLogs
```

Alternatively, you can just type the `find` command above directly into your Terminal if you have a good memory and like typing :-)

Comment: Why run `find`, then `rm`? You're hitting the filesystem twice (granted, the direntry cache will normally contain contents between them) rather than just storing the glob results once and using that twice -- once to write to the file, once to generate an argument list for `rm`.

Comment: (Also, since you aren't stopping `find` from recursing, `find` can list more files in this use case than `rm` then deletes).

Comment: ...in addition to adding `-maxdepth 1` to stop recursing unless you're sure it's wanted, you might also consider having just one `find` command that both prints filenames _and_ deletes the files. That would actually be better than the answer I have, if you use `-exec {} +` for the latter, since it would deal correctly with very long lists of files while not using more `rm`invocations than strictly necessary.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The OP was using `rm -r` which is also recursive, surely?

Comment: It doesn't make the glob expression recursive; it recursively deletes any _directory_ named ending in `.log`, but only if that directory is an immediate child of the current directory where the command is run.

Comment: (Making a glob expression recursive in bash requires running `shopt -s globstar` in bash 4.1 or newer, and using the `**` operator enabled by same; zsh has this operator available by default; POSIX shells don't have any equivalent at all).

Comment: if you use `find`, you can use `-delete`, no need `rm`

Comment: @YOU, that's a GNUism. No `-delete` in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html. Though, granted, I suggested `-maxdepth`, which is a GNUism itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think I got that, and have updated accordingly - thank you for your inputs.

Comment: thats old, my osx shell find have -delete option too. but well, documentation is documentation xD

Comment: The `;` is actually wrong here -- makes the `>>` its own command, rather than applying the redirection to the `find`. In the `-exec {} \;` use case, the `;` is an argument to `find`; in `-exec {} +`, the `+` replaces it; no explicit `;` is needed.

Comment: @YOU, as best as I can tell, `-delete` isn't present in even the very latest POSIX draft. Thus, I'm not sure that "old" is the way to describe said documentation: It's simply not part of the standard for what a minimal compliant implementation of `find` is expected to provide.

Comment: It does not log the removal for me, it does remove the file though???
cd /mnt/media/Torrents/watch;
date >> /mnt/media/Removal.txt;
find . -maxdepth 4 -name \*.invalid -print -exec rm {} +; >> /mnt/media/Removal.txt;

NB the date logs but not the result of the rm

Answer (score 0):

Given the use case clarified in comments -- that you're not trying to log *all* uses of `rm`, but a specific instance as invoked from a build process (or a cron job cleaning up after said build process):

```
printf '%s\n' *.log >>deletedFiles
rm -f -- *.log
```

Note that this won't distinguish between a file named `bar$'\n'foo` and two files named `bar` and `foo`; both will be logged with two consecutive lines. For that, you'd want to use either `'%q\n'` (if your shell is `bash`) or `%s\0` for your format string; the former would produce your log in eval-safe form (fairly easy for humans to read, hard to parse securely from shell); the latter would produce it in NUL-delimited form (hard for humans to read, easy to parse by machine in any language); either is unambiguous across all possible filenames.

Comment: I will have a try and will update if that works. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get rm running in a find command like above, this is seemingly the best practice find, remove, and log, and my solution for automation with shell script (not necessarily best practice)

From a shell script named `removelogs.sh`
run the command `sh removelogs.sh` in terminal

this is the text in removelogs.sh file.

```
cd /var/log;
date >> /var/log/removedlogs.txt;
find . -maxdepth 4 -type f -name \*log.old -delete -print >> /var/log/removedlogs.txt
```

- . - to run at this location **!!! so ensure you do not run this in root folder!!!**
- -maxdepth - to prevent it getting out of control
- -type - to ensure just files
- -name - to ensure just your filtered names
- -print - to send the result to stdout
- -delete - to delete said files
- >> - appends to files not overwrites > creates new file

works for me on CENTOS7